# Child hidden outside parent with display:inline-blox and overflow: auto

Tags: html, css

I am having some problems with the last child / the last child's margin being hidden outside the page/it's parent while the parent has max-height: -webkit-fill-available; height: auto; display:inline-block; and overflow: auto, as seen at https://jsfiddle.net/andreasjj/ok9hqgxv/2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body, html {
            font-size: 16px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        body {
            min-height: 100vh;
            height: 100vh;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        #root {
            height: inherit;
            min-height: inherit;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #wrapper {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            height: inherit;
            min-height: inherit;
            width: inherit;
        }
        #header {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            align-items: center;
            min-height: 50px;
            width: inherit;
            background-color: #f8f8f8;
        }
        #container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            width: inherit;
            height: inherit;
        }
        #content {
            height: inherit;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #box {
            display: flex;
            -webkit-box-align: center;
            align-items: center;
            -webkit-box-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
            height: inherit;
            width: inherit;
        }
        #box-content {
            max-height: -webkit-fill-available;
            height: auto;
            overflow: auto;
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 0.75rem;
            width: calc(100vw - 1.0rem);
            max-width: 900px;
        }
        .module {
            background-color: black;
            border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
            padding: 1.0rem;
            margin-bottom: 3rem;
            width: 541px;
            height: 461px;
        }
        .module:first-child {
            margin-top: 3rem;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header"></div>
            <div id="container">
                <section id="content">
                    <div id="box">
                        <div id="box-content">
                            <div class="module"></div>
                            <div class="module"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The last black box is missing most of its margin which is hidden (and if you remove the margin, part of the box itself will be hidden).

I have tried to change the height, max-height of different ancestors, in addition to different display values. But nothing seem to work. Any ideas?

*The structure of the html might seem a bit weird, but this is html and css extracted from a react app, so I'd like to keep the structure somewhat similar to not break the whole thing.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your problem, but what I always start my CSS scripts with, is the following piece of code:

```
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The * means 'select everything' and the box-sizing makes sure that all the extra's like margins and borders are included in the size of an object.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp

Hope it works for you!